# Pandas dataframe not correct format for groupby, what is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sum all columns based on the value of the first, but groupby.sum is unexpectedly not working.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex',10, 11],['Bob',12, 10],['Clarke',13, 9], ['Clarke',1, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','points1', 'points2'])
print(df)

df.groupby('Name').sum()

print(df)
```

I get this:

```
     Name  points1  points2
0    Alex       10       11
1     Bob       12       10
2  Clarke       13        9
3  Clarke        1        1
```

And not this:

```
     Name  points1  points2
0    Alex       10       11
1     Bob       12       10
2  Clarke       14       10
```

From what i understand, the dataframe is not the right format for pandas to perform group by. I would like to understand what is wrong with it because this is just a toy example but i have the same problem with a real data-set.

The real data i'm trying to read is the John Hopkins University Covid-19 dataset:

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget assign output of aggregation to variable, because aggregation not working inplace. So in your solution `print (df)` before and after `groupby` returned same original `DataFrame`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()  
print (df1)
     Name  points1  points2
0    Alex       10       11
1     Bob       12       10
2  Clarke       14       10
```

Or you can set to same variable `df`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()  
print (df)
     Name  points1  points2
0    Alex       10       11
1     Bob       12       10
2  Clarke       14       10
```

Comment: Ah yes, not inplace. \facepalm